# IntelliJ Artifact Auto-Import Maven Dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When creating an [`artifact`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/artifact.html?origin=old_help) in [`IntelliJ IDEA`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and adding dependencies to my [`pom.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html), the `artifact` dependencies are not updated. If I then export the `JAR` file using my `artifact` configuration assuming everything is fine, I will get a class not found exception since the dependencies were not fully exported.

Is there a way to make `IntelliJ` automatically use all dependencies for exporting? I understand that this is not always desired behavior when using multiple `artifacts` (to cut down on the file size) but mostly when only using one `artifact` it is preferred to not having to delete and recreate the artifact configuration frequently.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for [Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

Just import jar manually to project library

Project>Open Module Setting >Libraries>"+" sign in middle tab ( add new project library - from Maven) > type Your file and add it